# How to pass variable from Controller to Model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I just want to pass a variable whose input is taken using $this->input->post()
to a function in Modal.

My function in Model is

```
function get_name($email) {
    //$email = $this->input->post('email');  
    $this->db->select('first_name');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $query = $this->db->get('sign_up');
    return $query->row()->first_name;
}
```

And in return I want to get first_name returned from function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***First of all & All above.. User Input Must Be Pass Through Proper Validation & Sanitization***

*Now, you can use following Controller & Model example to get your result.*

***User Controller:***

```
<?php
// No direct Script execution
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * My User Controller
 *
 * Always make Controller Slim & Model Fat :)
 */
class User extends CI_Controller
{
    /**
     * Class Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // call parent constructor
        parent::__construct();
        // load your User_model
        $this->load->model('User_model');
    }

    /**
     * If method calling by Via Via...
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function validate_post(){
        // get email from POST
        $email = $this->input->post('email', true);
        // call another method
        $this->get_name($email);
    }

    /**
     * Get User First Name by Email ID
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function get_name($email)
    {
        // if user has session email
        if ($this->session->userdata('email')) {            
            // call model method to get first name
            $first_name = $this->User_model->get_name($email);

            // check what model returns
            if ($first_name === false) {
                // no record found
                show_error('Data error: Supplied email not in record.');
            } elseif ($first_name === null) {
                // invalid email format
                show_error('Validation error: Email is not valid.');
            } else {
                // Yes! you made it
                $this->display('Welcome Back !!! '.$first_name);
            }
        } else {
            // user not login, show them login page
            redirect('/');
        }
    }
}

/* End of file User.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/User.php */
```

---

***User_model Model:***

```
<?php
// No direct script execution
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * Class User_model to handle all user related information from MySQL
 */
class User_model extends CI_Model
{
    /**
     * MySQL table which contains all data about users
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'sign_up';

    /**
     * Returns, User First Name by Email ID
     * @param  [type] $email_addres   [description]
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function get_name($email_addres)
    {

        // validate email
        if (filter_var($email_addres, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // desire column from table
            $this->db->select('first_name');
            // where clause
            $this->db->where('email_addres', $email_addres);
            // mysql table
            $query = $this->db->get($this->table);

            // if record exist
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                // row, will return first result only, no matter if multiple record exist
                $ret = $query->row();
                // return first row, firs_name value
                return $ret->first_name;
            } else {
                // error
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // validation error
            return null;
        }
    }
}

/* End of file User_model.php */
/* Location: ./application/models/User_model.php */
```

Comment: @AmaanIqbal, are you sure..? you getting proper email in POST, are you sure you have that email matching record in mysql table, are you sure your query being created fine, are you sure while you dry run your query in phpmyadmin you getting data, are you sure your table column structure is proper... ? are you sure you hitting the right table.. are you sure your model function get called.. ??

Comment: Its returning      ' Validation error: Email is not valid. '

Comment: I guess I am not getting proper email using post

Comment: Hmm, so you are not passing email to method. Use a form that have email input and post that form to controller/method

Comment: The method using session to check whether user is login or not if user login and posting email to get_name method and if email is valid then surly you will get data....

Comment: My form is sending data to some other function inside controller for validation and then that function is redirecting to this one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147560/discussion-between-neeraj-singh-and-amaan-iqbal).

Comment: Codeigniter has form_validation library it can check is_valid for email saves you using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL

Comment: Yes, you are right.. But in example I m not using full library to check only email. So FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL is fine here for now.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below mentioned solution.

```
function get_name($email) {
    $this->db->select('first_name');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $query = $this->db->get('sign_up');
    $ret = $query->row();
    return $ret->first_name;
}
```

Let me know if it not work.

Comment: Check that you are getting value of `$email` or not. If you got value than share screenshot of your table

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to find the "first_name" in the table "sign_up", where "email" = $email. Did you try this approach:

```
$this->db->select("first_name");
$this->db->from("sign_up");
$this->db->where("email", $email);
$result = $this->db->get()->row();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass variable from Model to Controller, not from Controller to Model (for this example. Because you're fetching data from database and you should use Models to make it done). I think you should understand MVC logic before start coding.

Model:

```
public function get_name()
{
  $email = $this->input->post('email', true);

  $query = $this->db->get_where('sign_up', ['email' => $email])->row('first_name');
  return $query;
}
```

Controller:

```
public function some_function_name()
{
  $this->load->model('Your_model_name');
  $some_variable = $this->Your_model_name->get_name();
}
```

Note: If you're not using PHP7, use `array()` instead of brackets.

Comment: But nothing is being returned from function get_name()

Comment: So, do you post anything? If you don't, you can't get anything.

Comment: I found my mistake. I am submitting the form to some other function in the controller and then redirecting to my required function. Hence the values are not being accessed in the required function.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below to get the first name :

```
function get_name($email) {
   $firstName = "";
   $this->db->select("first_name");
   $this->db->from("sign_up");
   $this->db->where("email", $email);
   $query = $this->db->get();
   $result = $query->result_array();
   if(!empty($result)){
     $firstName = $result[0]['first_name'];
   }
   return $firstName;
 }
```

In the above function if the first name is present then it will be fetched and sent to controller in string format.

And please note that if there are many rows then also it will fetch the data from the first row of result since I have taken it's 0th element.